# Opensource Object Oriented Database for WPF application

Tags: database, oop

I am planning to implement an application using WPF, I want to use an Object Oriented database.

Could you suggest an Open Source Object Oriented Database?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [db40](http://www.db4o.com/) http://www.db4o.com/

they have a GPL version

if you wanna look for something else -

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_object_database_management_systems